# Beautify Ruby on Sublime Text2 problems

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, beautify-ruby

My "Beautify Ruby" package for Sublime Text 2 is acting really funny.  It is indenting `for` loops 4 spaces and `if` statements only 2 while all `end` statements are unindented 2 spaces.  My Sublime is set to use 2 spaces for tabs.  This is a new problem that seem to happen intermittently.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled "Beautify Ruby" but no change.

```
for n in (0..100) do
    if some_if_statement
      2_spaces_here
    elsif 2_spaces_back
      2_spaces_again
    end
  end # and now the end is not aligned with the for loop?
```

It also acts strangely in other circumstances but I don't know what the 'rules' for how it's behaving are. For example:

```
  if numerator/denominator < 0.10
                  return current_num_between_corners -1
                  end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd suggest opening an [issue](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby/issues) on the project's GitHub page with clear before-and-after code blocks and any configuration settings you might have customized. Come to think of it, that wouldn't hurt for this question, either. Show us what you had before, how it ended up, and what you were expecting. Config settings are also very helpful...